# AngularJS expression with custom "filter"?

Tags: angularjs, expression

I'm using GET to load some user profile data, like so -

> MainController.js

```
   $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: config.serverUrl + '/profile'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.userdata = response.data.message.user;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
         toastr.error('Something is wrong.');
    });
```

> Server response

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": {
        "user": {
            "id": 36,
            "email": "user@gmail.com",
            "name": "Rusty Rittenhouse"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm using the following expression to show the user's name:

```
{{ userdata.name }} -> inputs "Rusty Rittenhouse"
```

**How can I display only "Rusty"?** Usually I would use split, but since I'm new to angular I don't know what's the best and most neat solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) to do this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('firstName', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input.split(' ')[0];
    };
});
```

and use it like so:

```
{{ userdata.name | firstName }}
```

or even better:

```
<div/span ng-bind="userdata.name | firstName"></div/span>
```

Comment: wow, thanks, its pretty neat. would you say it is right to use a filter in this case?

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't want to actually modify the original data and it's not a heavy function using a filter is fine, just remember that a filter can run hundreds of times so keep it light

Comment: I only get to try it out now. It's not working for some reason "input" is undefined. any idea?

Comment: Could it be that either userdata or userdata.name is undefined ?

Comment: You could always add: `return input ? input.split(' ')[0] : ' ';`

Comment: userdata is received through "http.get". something really weird is happening, actually. im getting many errors that "input"  is undefined, and then at some point it does work.

Comment: It tries to fire the filter before your data is loaded, if you add the code from my last comment you shouldn't have the error anymore

Comment: alright i see, so it is indeed better to use ng-bind. thank you, i learned a lot.